# Want a button that add the product in cart and redirect to checkout page instead of view cart page:Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I am working with Magento. all I want just a button that add a product to cart and then go to check out page not to view cart. means I want direct order for the registered users. and I am working in **PORTO Magento theme**
I have tried it by creating copy of function **addAction** of cartController.php(app/code/core/checkout/controllers/) to myaddAction().

**added  below JS to end** view.phtml(app/design/frontend/your package/your template/template/catalog/product/view.phtml)

```
  productAddToCartForm.submitmy = function(button, url){
  replaceURL = url.replace("add/","myadd/");
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = replaceURL;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

and changed addaction to myaddAction in cart controller and also changed

```
$this->_goBack();
to
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
        return;
```

But I am getting an error undefined funtion,
 productAddToCartForm.submitmy

please hope someone help.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an observer on `add_to_cart_after` and then set a redirect here.  Something as simple as:

```
$response = $observer->getResponse();
$url = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
$response->setRedirect($url);
die();
```